# Angular argument is not a function: got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying a simple test code to check the Angular frontend, and running in this issue where it declares my function as undefined.

Here is my implementation:

EventDetails.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="eventsApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Event Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css"/>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-controller="EventController">
            {{event.name}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/underscore-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/controllers/EventController.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

EventController.js

```
'use strict'

eventsApp.controller('EventController',
    function EventController($scope) {
        $scope.event = {
            name: 'Angular Boot Camp',
            date: '1/1/2013',
            time: '10:30 am'
        }
    }
);
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', []);
```

web-server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../');

app.use(express.static(rootPath + '/app'));

app.listen(8000);
console.log('Listening on port 8000.....');
```

I am running this on angualr version 1.4.0

Any help will be much appreciated

Error Code :

Google Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Directory Structure:

[image]

So looks like a 404 is there, but not sure why . Tried resetting browser clearing caches and things. But the directory structure is right

Comment: Can you post your complete `error information` and as well as complete code for `EventController.js` ?

Comment: Check if your eventcontroller.js loaded

Comment: Your filename, according to your screenshot is `EventController` (no extension). You should rename that to `EventController.js`

Comment: Thanks I am not sure how I could make such a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is , invalid path of controller pls check that 
or you forgot that js file extension, you are given `EventController` instead of `EventController.js`

Comment: Thanks I am not sure how I could make such a mistake.